# Printing odd numbers using Iterators

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, iteration

```
class OddNum():
   def __next__(x):
      if x%2 != 0:
         print x


def main():
    a = iter(OddNum(1))
    while next(a)<100:
        try:
            print(next(a))
        except StopIteration:
            break

main()
```

Above is the code I am working with. The main code was given, so I did not write that. All this is supposed to do is print odd numbers 1-100.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 36, in <module>
    main()
  line 29, in main
    a = iter(OddNum(1))
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Comment: Something seems wrong here, you're calling `next` twice and discarding every other odd number. Why is this done?

Comment: Please post the code you tried, along with the error you got.

Comment: The main was given I did not write that so I dont know

Comment: I posted what I tried and the error

Comment: Well, have you considered writing a constructor for your class - one that takes arguments - so you don't get that error?

Comment: To write an iterator class, you generally need to define all of `__init__`, `__iter__`, and `__next__`.

Comment: It's also pretty weird that the `main` test function checks for `StopIteration`, as if the assignment expected your iterator to guess how far it's supposed to go and then stop at some point…

Comment: Your `class OddNum` has no `__init__()` constructor method defined, which is why you got the error message (because you tried to pass it an argument).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were assigned a trick question.

The given `main` function actually grabs *two* values from your iterator each time through the loop, but only prints the second one. So, your `OddNum` iterator needs yield each number twice in a row.

---

But notice that this means you can simplify the problem: just make `OddNum(n)` yield *all* numbers starting from `n-1`. So, if you call it on `OddNum(1)`, the `main` function will first get a `0`, see that it's `< 100`, then fetch and print the `1`, then get a `2` and see that it's `< 100`, then fetch and print the `3`, and so on.

Which means your answer can be as simple as:

```
def OddNum(n):
    return itertools.count(n-1)
```

Or, if you want to write it out explicitly:

```
def OddNum(n):
    n -= 1
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1
```

Or, if you want to write it as an iterator class rather than a generator:

```
class OddNum:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n-1
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    # For Python 3, rename this to __next__
    def next(self):
        n = self.n
        self.n += 1
        return n
```

---

Of course if you don't want to take advantage of this trick (or think your instructor doesn't want you to), you should be able to change any of the above to count odd numbers and yield them twice. In fact, if I were you, I'd write it both ways, with appropriate comments, to prove that I understood the question and what's happening under the covers, rather than just turning in my code above.

Comment: hehe nice, you addressed my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989288/printing-odd-numbers-in-python-using-iterators#comment86995101_49989288) asking exactly this.

Comment: @JebusCrust hope you're willing to share some of your assignment credit with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I really hope the instructor actually _was_ asking a trick question; if they assigned this without realizing the obvious bug in `main`, the OP is going to have a hard time learning anything from this course…

Comment: THis is the error im getting now after implementing your code: Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 36, in <module>
    main()
 line 29, in main
    while next(a)<100:
TypeError: instance has no next() method

Comment: @JebusCrust Ah, you're using Python 2? Then you shouldn't have been trying to write a `__next__` method in the first place; that's Python 3. Updated the answer. But really, if you don't understand even that much of the iterator protocol, it's going to be pretty obvious to your teacher that you don't know what you're doing, so I'd go back and reread the book/notes/whatever.

Comment: I will, but yes it is python 2 and I have used that method in  every other code as well

Comment: thanks everyone but i will take your responses and look at the notes again

Comment: @JebusCrust Unless you were using Python 3, or using a modernizing decorator or superclass or metaclass or some kind that forwards `next` to `__next__`, all of your other code is wrong too. See [Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) in the docs: there is nothing named `__next__` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awful assignment, because it makes no semantic sense. `main()` calls `next()` twice, so you only need to increment a counter only `1` every call, e.g.:

```
class OddNum():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x
```

This prints: `3, 5, 7, 9, ..., 99`

Comment: I have to use the method named __next__ to compute and print the odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `Generator Expression` in Python to print odd numbers 1-100 and save them in a `list`.:

```
odd_num = (x for x in range(100)
           if x % 2 == 1)

# print every single odd number:
# for i in odd_num:
#     print(f"Odd numbers are: {i}")

odd_num_list = list(odd_num)
print(f"odd_num_list is {odd_num_list}")
```

This returns:

```
odd_num_list is [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```